# estimation of a unit circle - how to show a relationship

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, math-history

It has been eons since I've done any trigonometry, but I just can't prove how this following relationship holds for $n = 4, 8, 16, 32, \dots$

The relation is:
$$
2 \biggl( \! \frac{A_{2n}}{n} \! \biggr)^2 = \, 1 - \Biggl( \sqrt{1 - \frac{2A_n^{\phantom{X}}}{n}} \, \Biggr)^{\!2}
$$

Any help would be appreciated.

---

***Progress:***

In this case, our $A_n$ can be given by the rule: $\frac{n \sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})}{2}$

We can expand $\text{LHS} = 2 \sin^2(\frac{\pi}{n})$

and $\text{RHS} = 1 - \sqrt{1-\sin^2(\frac{2\pi}{n})}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I properly understand; forgive me if I am stupid.

If $$\text{RHS} = 1 - \sqrt{1-\sin^2(\frac{2\pi}{n})}=1-\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})$$ but $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$ which makes $$\text{RHS} =2 \sin^2(\frac{\pi}{n})=\text{LHS}$$

Comment: Yea @Claude, that's fine. I'd solved it shortly I figured out the $A_n = \dots$ but couldn't be bothered updating it here till now!>

Thanks anyway though :)

Comment: @piman314. You are very welcome !